# Git Bash cannot resolve %userprofile%

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro and Git 2.7.1.windows.2.

My problem is quite self-explanatory:

```
xehpuk@XEHPUK MINGW64 /d/the-next-big-thing (develop)
$ git pull
Could not create directory '/%userprofile%/.ssh'.
percent_expand: unknown key %/
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

xehpuk@XEHPUK MINGW64 /d/the-next-big-thing (develop)
$ cd ~
bash: cd: /%userprofile%: No such file or directory

xehpuk@XEHPUK MINGW64 /d/the-next-big-thing (develop)
$ echo $USERPROFILE
C:\Users\xehpuk
```

This worked a few days ago and I cannot remember changing anything on the system.

Obviously, I am a Git beginner and a primary Windows user, if that's important.

---

I have worked around the issue by setting the user environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `"/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh.exe" -i /c/Users/xehpuk/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 8):

September 2021, Git for Windows.
I had the following error when trying to fetch sources from Jenkins:

```
stderr: vdollar_percent_expand: unknown key %U
```

To fix, set the environment variable `HOME` equals to `%USERPROFILE%`:

[image]

Comment: You can also do it from an elevated cmd (with admin rights) with the following: 
`setx -m HOME %USERPROFILE%`

Comment: This worked for me. Any idea why?  OpenSSH just expects it to be there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple to fix:

You simply need to set an HOME variable under your system properties in windows and set the home to your local user-profile folder

[image]